# How to integrate in best way yarn package with Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have always problem how to integrate third party yarn package to Rails 6 project in the simplest way, for example `@tabler/core`. I know that I could do `require("@tabler/core")` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` but not sure how it works and what it does. Also in tabler node_modules folder are other third party packages that tabler is using, how to import all stuff at once in the best and simplest way?

Answer (score 1):

> but not sure how it works and what it does

I would add https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer to see what webpacker is adding in `packs/application.js`.

Here is how `webpack/development.js` looks like:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const environment = require('./environment');

environment.plugins.append('BundleAnalyzerPlugin', new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
```

That should give you enough information about what it does.

I am not using `tabler`, but from their git page `require("@tabler/core")` should bring all the stuff.

Comment: thanks, but css/sass files are not included when ```require("@tabler/core")``` or any other package with css/sass files, I need add this manually?

Comment: Yes css/scss files should be added manually. In webpcaker config you should have extract_css: true and in packs/application.js at the top do `@import "@tabler/core"` or @import path_to_tabler_css if the previous does not work. Then in your views stylesheet_pack_tag :application. Somethin like that.

Comment: thanks so much, but what with third libs that are in tabler node_modules folder in "lib"? as I see in package.json of tabler there are these dependencies like apexcharts and bootstrap but webpack-bundle-analyzer doesn't show this dependencies, just load only @table/core/dis/js/tabler.js I also need load these dependecies manually in packs/application.js?

Comment: If you need them and require doesn't bring them in then yes, manually import. Now that you ahve bundle analyzer import/require what you like and see what it does. Make your code work :)

Comment: Out of curiosity that CDN link from their github page, does it bing everything, or just core?